# How do you generate an image of a specific size in Java?

Tags: java, file, image-processing, graphics, java-io

I need to generate images (the format of images does not matter) of a given size (For example, `10KB`, `100KB`, `1MB`, `10MB`, etc), using **Java**. The image can be any shape which is filled a background color, no restrictions for the content of images.

**Edit #1:** The sizes of the images which are going to be created are changeable, so I am looking for **an efficient way** in terms of **memory usage** in order to be safe from the **Java** `heap space` exception while creating images.

**Edit #2:** I am getting the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dimensions (width=48000 height=48000) are too large` exception when I try to generate an image with the dimensions `48000x48000` using the Graphics2D library, which is necessary in order to generate images with large file sizes.

**Edit #3:** When the dimensions get bigger, I experience the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exception even though I have manually configured the `-Xmx` parameter of the Java program that does this.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281195/creating-images-with-a-java/19281350#19281350

Comment: I have a size criteria too which is the key part of the question.

Comment: Of course, I am aware of these parameters but I need to create images of various sizes. Also, I am asking **the most efficient way** of creating images in order to prevent any possible `heap size` exceptions.

Comment: `BufferedImage` is still your best bet, I've managed sizes of over 2,000x2,000 pixels before, but your requirements are unclear and broad.  The "most efficient way" is to ensure that you dispose of any unused resources when you're done with them

Comment: What are you doing with the images? Are you reading them and processing them in some manner? Are you drawing into them programmatically? How many images are you expecting to manage at once? Do you have any idea of the size ranges you might be expected to manage? Are you stuck using a single process or can you use multiple processes? You could simply store the image data in a byte array, which could allow you to devise your own disk cache, but it's manipulation becomes difficult and you lose the graphics support supplied by `BufferedImage` which would reduce your development time

Comment: Need to generate different images of various sizes (i.e. `10KB`, `100KB`, `1MB`, `10MB`, etc.) for an academic research.** The maximum file size** is expected to be `100MB`. No restrictions on the number of processes. **The number of images** needed to be generated is also part of the work - which is a number in the range of `1-1000` (i.e. `1`, `10`, `100`, `1000`).

Comment: Is that uncompressed size? Memory and disk are different issues. If you can, generate some or all of images in different processes, each will get there memory space, might help

Comment: For your EDIT 2: width * height should be less than Integer.MAX_VALUE. @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089675/creating-huge-bufferedimage

Comment: @opensam Could we use that as duplicate?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am fairly new on this site. Sorry

Comment: @opensam No apologies required, it just sounds like that would answer the question as I've been able to ascertain it :P

Comment: @talha06 Care to comment on my answer, if it doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: see my comment below your answer @haraldK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some very simple sample code that should match your requirements as far as I can understand. The program should work very efficiently with almost no memory at all, but will still create image files of sizes up to (roughly) 2GB (you can also easily adapt it to create much larger images, if you like).

Assumptions:

- The image format does not matter, so we'll choose the [PGM format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) (in binary 'P5' mode)
- The image can be any shape/color, so we'll just do the simplest thing and write one line of all black.
- The size that matters is the image file size (the code below doesn't write to the byte this size, but could easily be modified by subtracting the size of the minimal file header before writing to be exact).

Input is file size, followed by file name (you want to use `.pgm` as extension). As an example:

```
$ java -cp ... WritePGM 2147483640 foo.pnm
```

The above will create the largest possible image my JVM permits to read back, which is roughly 2 GB.

Code:

```
public class WritePGM {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        File file = new File(args[1]);

        try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
            // Format P5/binary gray
            out.write("P5\n".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            // Dimensions (width/height)
            out.write(String.format("%s 1\n", size).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            // MaxSample
            out.write("255\n".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            // Just write a single line of 0-bytes
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                out.write(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

PS: If you need an ImageIO plugin to read the generated file using Java, you can use JAI ImageIO or [my own PNM plugin](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys), but you will of course experience the same memory issues as when you tried to generate such images using Java2D (`BufferedImage`).

---

In theory, you could also use similar techniques for creating files in formats like JPEG or PNG, but these formats are *much* harder to implement. Also, they are compressed, so predicting the file size is hard.

Perhaps you could pad a minimal JPEG with extra non-image data, like XMP or so. PNG does allow writing Deflate blocks with no compression, which might be an option. Or use extra chunks for padding.

An uncompressed format like BMP will be simpler. You could use the same technique as above, just write a fixed, minimal BMP header, set the correct width and write the image data almost as above. BMP does need row padding, and doesn't support gray data, so you need to do some extra work. But certainly doable.

Comment: Really an efficient solution, works as expected, thanks for your contribution. What about generating well-known image formats such as `jpg`, `png`, etc.?

Comment: @talha06 Added a section about this at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way to generate a Gray Scale image(of width : width and height : height) :-

1) Create a [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) object :-

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
```

2) Populate your BufferedImage object (here I am assuming that you have proper input to the image stored in a 2-d array of int called img):-

```
for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) 
    {
      for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) 
      {

          image.setRGB(x, y, img[y][x]<<16 | img[y][x] << 8 | img[y][x]);
      }

    }
```

3) Write the BufferedImage object to disk :-

```
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new FileOutputStream(new File("SomePath/Name-of-Image.jpg")));
```

Comment: All good except the size criteria which is the key part of the question.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? Are you reading an image, doing some processing and then writing them back? or is it something else?

Comment: Need to generate different images of various sizes (i.e. 10KB, 100KB, 1MB, 10MB, etc.) for an academic research.

Comment: I agree with MadProgrammer(see his comment under your question). BufferedImage is still you best best. I once used it to process an image in a thousand different ways. What I did was, before doing the different set of processing, I would write the image onto disk first and free up the resources. You can follow similar pattern. With the information you have provided, this is the best advice I can give you

Comment: Thanks @opensam, agree with you; it fits best for me but having some issues while creating images especially when the dimensions of images are getting larger as I mentioned in the original post.

Answer (score -3):

- [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)
- [Working with Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/)
- [`Graphics 2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/index.html)

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281195/creating-images-with-a-java/19281350#19281350)